# Custom react-hook for dynamically setting css-classes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm currently playing and learning React's hooks. I wanted to re-use the capability to set an element's shadow (using `bootstrap` as css-framework).

This is what my `App` currently looks like:

```
export const App: React.FunctionComponent<IAppProps> = ({ }: IAppProps) => {
    // get shadow-classes for alert
    const [shadowClasses, setShadowClasses] = useShadow("none");

    // define callbacks when hovering the alert
    const handleMouseEnter = () => setShadowClasses("regular");
    const handleMouseOut = () => setShadowClasses("none");

    // return the markup to be used
    return (
        <Container>
            <Grid.Row>
                <Grid.Col>
                    <Alert color={Constants.Color.Danger} className={classNames(shadowClasses)} onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter} onMouseOut={handleMouseOut} >{"This is some kind of an alert ..."}</Alert>
                </Grid.Col>
            </Grid.Row>
        </Container>
    );
};
```

My goal is to have an shadow added when the `Alert` is hovered. Unfortunately nothing happens when hovering and I don't get the why.

Find below the implementation of my "custom hook":

```
export function useShadow(initialType: "none"|"sm"|"regular"|"large"): [string[], (type: "none"|"sm"|"regular"|"large") => void] {
    // define the classes to be used
    const classNames: string[] = [];

    // get the shadow's current value
    const [shadowType, setShadow] = React.useState(initialType);

    // set depending on given type
    switch (shadowType) {
        case "none":
            classNames.push(`shadow-none`);
            break;
        case Constants.BreakpointSize.Small:
            classNames.push(`shadow-sm`);
            break;
        case "regular":
            classNames.push(`shadow`);
            break;
        case Constants.BreakpointSize.Large:
            classNames.push(`shadow-lg`);
            break;
    }

    // define the callback to change the shadow
    const handleChange = (type: Type) => () => setShadow(type);

    // return the class-names and the change-callback
    return [classNames, handleChange];
}
```

I'm not even sure if this is correct way on how to use custom hooks or not.

** Update **

I created a `useSpacing` hook to set spacing of elements which is implemented like:

```
export function useSpacing(initialSpacingProps: ISpacingProps[] = []): [string[], (spacingProps: ISpacingProps[]) => void] {
    // get the state-value
    const [spacingProps, setSpacingProps] = React.useState(initialSpacingProps);

    // create the result holding the class-names
    const spacingClasses: string[] = [];

    // loop through given spacing-definitions
    for (let spacingProp of spacingProps) {
        // get the values
        const { breakpoint, property, side, size, negative } = spacingProp;

        // handle depending on breakpoint
        spacingClasses.push(`${property}${side}${breakpoint !== Constants.BreakpointSize.ExtraSmall ? `-${breakpoint}` : ``}-${negative && size !== Size.Auto ? `n` : ``}${size}`);
    }

    // define the callback when the value should be changed
    const handleChange = (newSpacingProps: ISpacingProps[]) => setSpacingProps(newSpacingProps);

    // return the classes
    return [spacingClasses, handleChange];
}
```

and is used this way:

```
export const App: React.FunctionComponent<IAppProps> = ({ }: IAppProps) => {
    const initialSpacingProps = [
        {
            breakpoint: Constants.BreakpointSize.ExtraSmall,
            property: Spacing.Property.Margin,
            side: Spacing.Side.LeftRight,
            size: Spacing.Size.Two
        }
    ];

    const clickedSpacingProps = [
        {
            breakpoint: Constants.BreakpointSize.Small,
            property: Spacing.Property.Padding,
            side: Spacing.Side.TopBottom,
            size: Spacing.Size.Five
        }
    ];

    // get the classes to apply spacing accordingly
    const [spacingClasses, setSpacingClasses] = useSpacing(initialSpacingProps);

    // define the callback when jumbotron gets clicked
    const handleClick = React.useCallback(() => setSpacingClasses(clickedSpacingProps), []);

    // return the markup to be used
    return (
        <Container>
            <Grid.Row>
                <Grid.Col>
                    <Shadows.Shadow type={Constants.BreakpointSize.Large}>
                        <Jumbotron className={classNames(spacingClasses)} onClick={handleClick}>
                            <h1 className="display-4">Hello, world!</h1>
                        </Jumbotron>
                    </Shadows.Shadow>
                </Grid.Col>
            </Grid.Row>
        </Container>
    );
};
```

When clicking the jumbotron-element, the new spacing is applied correctly

Comment: Are `handleMouseEnter` and `handleMouseOut ` being executed?

Comment: @FernandoMontoya yes, they are. I've added a `console.log` and both are showing for enter and out. I've also added a log in the hook's `handleChange` which never got hit.

Comment: Have you tried changing `handleChange` to use `useCallback` Hook?

Comment: @FernandoMontoya tried and still got not hit

Comment: I also don't see how by calling `setShadow` it is going to affect `classNames`. Seems like a good use case for `useReducer`.

Comment: @FernandoMontoya I've updated my question as I also had a `useSpacing` hook which works as expected and why I am wondering why `useShadow` does not

Comment: Found the error: `handleChange` is a function returning another function, remove the second `=> ()` in its declaration, see it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-gould-offv6.

Comment: As you can see in the `useSpacing` Hook, `handleChange` it is a function that calls `setSpacingProps` directly.

Comment: @FernandoMontoya you are a life saver! Please post as answer so I can get you the credit you deserve ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `handleChange` function is returning another function, removing the second function will fix it.

```
const handleChange = (type: Type) => setShadow(type);
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-gould-offv6